# In, QFT, do the excitations in the quantum fields exist physically?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

In QFT, all particles are really just excitations in their quantum fields, and we know that these fields are just mathematical.For example, an electron is an excitation of the electron field. But my question is, is the excitation of the field (the particle) mathematical too, or is it physically real? And if the excitations of the fields do not really physically exist, does that mean that reality doesn't physically exist either?

Comment: What, exactly, does "physically exist" mean to you? Particles make blips in detectors, they're real. We describe them by math in the theory. Being described by math and being real are not mutually exclusive, I don't know what you're trying the ask here.

Comment: In Newtonian mechanics, do particles exist physically?  I don't know what your answer will be because (as @ACuriousMind notes) you haven't chosen to tell us what you mean by "exist physically".  But Newtonian mechanics is exactly as mathematical as QFT, so whatever your answer might be to the Newtonian question, that should be your answer to the QFT question as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is an experimentalist's view.

Here is a definition of a [field in physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28physics%29):

> In physics, a field is a physical quantity that has a value for each point in space and time

................

> A field can be classified as a scalar field, a vector field, a spinor field or a tensor field according to whether the represented physical quantity is a scalar, a vector, a spinor or a tensor, respectively.

.................

> Moreover, within each category (scalar, vector, tensor), a field can be either a classical field or a quantum field, depending on whether it is characterized by numbers or **quantum operators** respectively. In fact in this theory an equivalent representation of field is a field particle, namely a boson.

(bold mine)

You state:

> For example, an electron is an excitation of the electron field.

Take an electron describing a trajectory in space time. At the (x,y,z,t) point a creation operator creates it and at (x+delta(x), y+delta(y),z +delta(z) t+delta(t)) destroys it to be picked up by the next (x',y',z',t') creation .... The functional form of the trajectory is described by the solution of the appropriate quantum mechanical solution of the boundary condition problem.

Having disposed of the luminiferous aether QFT manages to create an underlying structure where excitations propagate defining particles. The difference lies in that Lorenz invariance holds for these fields.

> But my question is, is the excitation of the field (the particle) mathematical too, or is it physically real? And if the excitations of the fields do not really physically exist, does that mean that reality doesn't physically exist either?

The particles are real in the sense they have macroscopic effects and are [measured in our laboratories.](http://hst-archive.web.cern.ch/archiv/HST2005/bubble_chambers/BCwebsite/index.htm)

The mathematics of field theory is real, as real as the parabolas predicted for throwing a ball in a gravitational field.

QFT is a mathematical model to deal with the  many body problem of quantum mechanics

Comment: So does the kink in the field show that something physical is really there?

Comment: There is no kink, there is a creation of an excitation of the electron field from one 4d point to the next . In a 4d plot it would trace the electrons track but to "see" it an interaction has to happen, and the electron will have a probability to be seen given by the Feynman diagram for the interaction. Before interaction it is all mathematics,  like the mathematical parabola of the thrown  ball : we see the ball because we interact with the reflected photons from the ball otherwise we would only have the theoretical parabola. The ball is real at one point at a time, the same with the electron

Comment: but we would have to interact to gauge its reality.

Comment: Are you saying that before we interact the electron is doesn't exist?

Comment: No , we do not know where it is unless the electron interacts with something, as in the bubble chamber picture I linked. Its existence or not depends on the boundary conditions of our quantum mechanical setup. The electron in the bubble chamber is seen because of continual interactions with atoms in the chamber, ionizing them and making little bubbles.

Comment: So the electron does exist, but we just don't know where it is, right?

Comment: We can prepare an experiment with an electron, yes, it does exist. The electron field is mathematical and exists everywhere and everywhen, but real electrons, the excitations, exist and we measure their traces. A beam of electrons going through vacuum, before hitting a detector exists, because of the boundary conditions that we created it. We only see it at the detector and can mathematically deduce its unseen track , the same with the parabola.

Answer (score 1):

So called "particle states" (momentum eigenstates) in QFT are not part of the Hilbert space (they are not normalizable), but only the rigged Hilbert space. As such, they cannot actually be physical states. Real states corresponding to real particles are more likely to be somewhat localized in both position and momentum.

The particle states are very useful as a basis for wavefunctions, though, similar to sine waves in a Fourier transform.

Answer (score 1):

Properties of the quantum fields (its mass density, charge density, response to external fields, etc.) can be measured and predicted in the same way as all quantum observables. There is therefore nothing unreal about a quantum field. They are at least as real as their excitations, the elementary particles.

In fact, quantum fields are far more physical than mathematical. In particular, interacting quantum fields in 4 dimensions do not yet make mathematical sense, while physicists use them all the time.

The field is what really exists, i.e., the medium, and the excitations are its oscillations. Just like water waves are excitations (local, extended oscillations) of water, which is the medium carrying the waves. The main difference is that water waves are not quantized, so that there are no 'elementary' excitations.

Comment: careful there, or we go back to ether. the lorenz invariance needs to be stressed.

Comment: @annav: Yes and No. Relativistic quantum fields have taken over the role of the ether. But due to more than a century of experience, there is no longer a serious discrepancy with experiment. -- Also, the term ''mechanics'' mo longer means what it meant at the time of the M/M experiment. It is no longer tied to materials but just refers to the existence of a Hamiltonian or Lagrangian description.